# Constructing a Hot Towel Breeze API

Tags: asp.net, breeze, hottowel

I'm building a fairly basic CRUD app based on Hot Towel SPA.

My plan is to use an ASP.NET web API to expose data to Breeze.

Is that the correct architecture?

At present I have four projects:

- DomainClassLibrary which contains the model T4 file (*.tt) and the partial classes to extend my EF model
- a DataClassLibrary which has the rest of the model (all this is per Julie Lerman on Pluralsight)
- a Hot Towel SPA app
- an ASP.NET web application HTTP Web API

Is my next step to build all of the controllers within the web api project to expose get, put, etc?

And then do I create a Breeze API that consumes the controllers in my web API project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hot Towel contains all of the prerequisite components so all you should need is a single project containing Hot Towel.  I think you're making it more complex than it needs to be.

John Papa has an excellent course on Pluralsight that walks you through Hot Towel.  Although I'm not using Hot Towel (I shifted to Angular), this course really helped me understand the fundamentals of building a SPA on .Net.

Comment: You are right. I thought I had to build the API and that Breeze would consume that but it actually replaces all the controllers with a simpler one. Thanks!

Comment: Check out my newest course and HotTowel.Angular .... I package I created that makes it easy to use Angular

Comment: I'm halfway through the new Angular/Breeze course now - it is excellent and helping me wrap up everything nicely.  Now if HotTowel would only include authentication and authorization it would be perfect!